# Limited localisation/multilingualism in TYPO3

Tags: yaml, localization, typo3, typoscript, typo3-11.x

TYPO3 11. PHP 8.1.
There is a big project where there was no multilingualism until now. A new language is to be added (DE), but only for the news extension. A language switcher is also to be implemented.

I have added the German language with strict mode and EN fallback and created the language switcher for news/tag list and news section. Everything works as intended, but there is a problem with links. When I switch to German translation in the frontend, ALL internal links on the page have such URL's: "domainname.com/en/...", although no translation is available for these pages.

In this case, how can you assign all links without translation, regardless of the language, to the default domain ("domainname.com/..."), is it even possible?

Many thanks in advance

Here is the part of the site configuration:

```
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ''
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: 0
    solr_core_read: ''
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: de_DE.utf8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-de
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: de
    solr_core_read: ''
    languageId: 1
```

When removing fallback the following happens: The links are not generated at all and instead of links there is only the text.
An intermediate solution is to define the parameter language="0" for the typolinks, but this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: When you say ALL internal Links. Are you then talking about the website navigation(menu). Maybe the problem is how you generate your menu?!